# What is the difference between present continuous and future continuous?

Tags: grammar, difference

1. What time are you meeting Jane?
   What time will you be meeting Jane?
2. Henry is not coming to the party next week.
   Henry will not be coming to the party next week.
3. What time are you arriving?
   What time will you be arriving?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to know if there is a difference in meaning between those sentence pairs?

Comment: Jason Bassford, Yes.I do want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal use, the sentence pairs they are essentially the same.

However, there is a subtle difference. It applies equally to each of the pairs, so I will focus on the first.

Note that in the following, this difference would probably not apply, but I'm pointing it out because there *could* be such a difference in the right situation.

- What time are you meeting Jane?
  This is asking about something that is currently planned. The meeting with Jane is scheduled, and the question is asking the time of that schedule. "Let me check. Ah, here it is in my calendar. I meet her at 10:30."
- What time will you be meeting Jane?
  Let's suppose there is no such calendar entry. However, you have very firm plans of making one Or, let's suppose that Jane doesn't even know who you are, and you haven't even contacted her yet. However, you fully intend to introduce yourself and set up a meeting with her at some point. In both cases, the meeting does not *actually* exist. But you can still answer the question if you have the *intention* of meeting her anyway. "Currently, there is no meeting. But I intend for it to be at 10:30."

In short:

- The *what time **are** you* form expresses something actually ***in existence*** as a plan for the future.
- The *what time **will** you* form expresses something that is an ***intention*** about the future.

---

The other two pairs have the same distinction, although if you analyze the negative version similarly, it could be given a sinister light.

For instance, a villain in a story who is not willing to let Henry attend the party, even though his attendance has already been planned, would be more likely to say *Henry **will not** be coming*, if the villain is thinking of arranging an accident for him. The ***is not*** version is still possible in this sense, but probably more likely if the villain has *already* arranged that accident.

---

This can be a very subtle difference in meaning, and the distinction is often not made. For practical purposes, the two forms are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here.

First:

- Present continuous is often used to talk about something that happens in the near future.

"Near future" is dependent on context.

> What time are you meeting Jane?

We can probably assume you're meeting Jane sometime before the end of the day.

Second:

- Modals are used to impart politeness and substitute for imperatives/commands in many settings, such as a business setting.

*Will* is a modal.  But *will X* of course still means X in the future.

Because of this, someone may prefer to use *when will you X* to get an official answer or commitment from someone, rather than *what time are you X'ing*.

Comment: I still don’t understand what you mean: “Will is a modal. But will X of course still means X in the future.

Because of this, someone may prefer to use when will you X to get an official answer or commitment from someone, rather than what time are you X'ing.”. Could you clarify?

Comment: Overall saying one may chose *will* to be polite or formal.

Answer (score 0):

The difference involves what I call a situational "when":

"What time are you meeting Jane?" is a straightforward question.

However,
"What time **will you be** meeting Jane?" implies the the speaker already knows something about the situation. When something has happened or is happening, the question is asked in this way because the speaker already knows, for example, that something like "**when** we get to Dallas" in the future is implied.

This is very similar to the past continuous, the past prefect continuous and the past perfect, which also usually imply a when situation which may be given specifically in the conversation or just implied by the context:

- What were you doing yesterday (when the game was on TV)?
- What had you done yesterday (when your sister arrived)?
- What had you been doing (when the doorbell rang)?
- What will you be doing next year? [future situation: when school starts or when COVID-19 is no longer a threat).

The when situation can be implicit or explicit, which is what can make this tricky for learners.